# Using multiple math fonts causes characters and spacing problems with delimiters

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, math-fonts

I am using Pagella as my main math font but MnSymbol for the \mathcal font and this has strange interactions.

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
 $\big||a| - |b|\big|\leq|a-b|$
\end{document}
```

compiles to

[image: base code]

In relation with the answer that worked well for [my previous problem with the range feature of unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386928/103608), I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range={up,it,tt,bb,frak, scr}]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}  %% NEW
\begin{document}
 $\big||a| - |b|\big|\leq|a-b|$
\end{document}
```

which improves things but leaves some ununderstandable space :
[image: trying to improve things]

I would like this inequation to look like this (achieved by not using MnSymbol at all, but I want it for my mathcal !)

[image: desired output]

Note : in this example, replacing the explicit `\big` by `\left` and `\right` gives a correct output, even without the workaround. But this `\left. \frac12 \right)` gives the same strange glyph for the left delimiter (although the workaround eliminates this one !).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\setmathfontface` to setup up a `\mathXX` font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfontface\mathcal{MnSymbol}[]

\begin{document}
 $\mathcal{A} \big||a| - |b|\big|\leq|a-b|$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works --- what is the point of the cal range in unicode-math then ?

Alas, the workaround in the referred question still causes the "additional spacing" problem. I am going to unaccept and comment [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386928/103608).

Comment: The cal-range is mainly there to change the `\symcal`-font and changes `\mathcal` in a sort of side effect. But the range option is as I already mentioned buggy and difficult to handle with math fonts. With non-math fonts (like MnSymbol) it is simply a pain.