# "Nice" square brackets

Tags: brackets

I am trying to get square brackets to fit "nicely" around a number (for denoting the equivalence class containing that number). Using the following,

```
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
\hline
$[0]$  & $[0]$  & $[1]$  & $[2]$ \\
$[1]$  & $[1]$  & $[2]$  & $[3]$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

There is superfluous whitespace under the numbers inside the brackets, which looks a bit jarring in a large table containing a lot of expressions like these. I would prefer something like this:

[image]

Notice how there is no superfluous whitespace under the numbers inside the brackets. I know that brackets can be made taller with `\bigl` and such. Is there a similar  way to make brackets shorter, or fit nicely around a number?

I used the default Computer Modern font. The ssecond example comes from a textbook typeset in Latex with the Gyre Schola font.

Comment: This question might be simpler to answer with a MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. You could choose a different typeface or replace the the brackets with brackets from another typeface as done in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386928/picking-single-glyph-with-setmathfont-range-modifies-other-glyphs.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` are wrong here and `[1]` is correct, however, that's just good general advice, `[1]` won't make any difference when it comes to your problem

Comment: Please tell us which font you're using.

Comment: the delimiters in the computer modern fonts are designed to be appropriate for more variable math environments, where often the material to be placed inside includes descenders, as on "p", "q", "y", or "`\chi`", as well as operator symbols centered vertically on the math axis. it's a different requirement.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use the `graphicx` package to scale the square brackets and use `\boldmath` to get slightly thicker brackets. Furthermore, you can combine this with a `\kern` and double up the brackets to get slightly thicker brackets:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\TightBracketB}[1]{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{\boldmath${#1\kern-0.65ex#1}$}}}%
\newcommand*{\TightBoxB}[1]{\TightBracketB[#1\TightBracketB]}

\newcommand{\TightBracketA}[1]{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{\boldmath${#1}$}}}%
\newcommand*{\TightBoxA}[1]{\TightBracketA[#1\TightBracketA]}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
\hline
$\TightBoxA{0}$  & $\TightBoxA{1}$  & $\TightBoxA{2}$  & $\TightBoxA{3}$ & $\TightBoxA{4}$ \\
$\TightBoxA{5}$  & $\TightBoxA{6}$  & $\TightBoxA{7}$  & $\TightBoxA{8}$ & $\TightBoxA{9}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
\hline
$\TightBoxB{0}$  & $\TightBoxB{1}$  & $\TightBoxB{2}$  & $\TightBoxB{3}$ & $\TightBoxB{4}$ \\
$\TightBoxB{5}$  & $\TightBoxB{6}$  & $\TightBoxB{7}$  & $\TightBoxB{8}$ & $\TightBoxB{9}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```